# case insensitive postgres search with multiple columns

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to create a contact form search in PHP.

Example entry:

> Name: Pink
>
> Phone: 555-888-1234

I want to search input boxes for name and phone and return LIKE matching results case insensitive.

Examples:

Search for 'p' in name and no phone number and get back the result.

Search for '5' in phone number field and no name, get result.

Search for "x" in name field, get no results, currently I get the result.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name ~* '.*$name.*' OR phone ~* '.*$phone.*'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine (but do not actually run it!) what happens if you put this in the name field:

```
');DROP TABLE contacts;--
```

[Welcome to SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Bye bye contacts table, unless you were sensibly running with a user that isn't the table owner - but even then `DELETE FROM contacts;` will probably work.

---

At a guess, what's happening is that you're substituting the empty string for `phone` or `name` if it's blank. So given `.*$phone.*` that produces  a regexp like `.*.*` which is of course *match anything*. Since there's an `OR` clause, your test with blank phone and name=`x` tests

```
name ~* '.*x.*' OR phone ~* '.*.*'
```

which is of course true for any value in `name`.

You should've been able to tell this by looking at the queries that actually got run. Turn on `log_statement=all` in `postgresql.conf` and use the PostgreSQL query logs.

---

What you need to do instead is:

- Build the query on the fly. If there's no entry in the filter for `phone`, leave off the `OR phone ~* ...` clause entirely.
- Use query parameters to properly inject your values into the query. You can do this even if you're concatenating values by doing the concatenation client-side or with something like:

  ```
  WHERE name ~* '.*'||$1||'.*'
  ```

  where `$1` is the query parameter placeholder. I don't remember if PHP uses that or `?` or whatever; see the documentation.
- Escape regular expression metacharacters in your values before sending them as parameters. Otherwise a search for a `phone` with `(` will produce a syntax error because of an invalid regexp.

Comment: I'm using pg_query_params and passing and user input as a parameter in our real code, this was a simplified example, but yes thank you for pointing out the SQL injection vulnerability. I do have logging on in postgres but didn't think to look there, that will come in handy. It looks like building the query on the fly will work, although I'll also have to account for whether to include OR if someone doesn't enter the first value. I'll have to test whether I still need to escape regex if they are passed as a parameter, hopefully not.

Comment: @apuschak You do still have to escape regex that are passed as parameters, because their regular expression metachars will still be significant. Unfortunately I don't think PostgreSQL has a built-in `regexp_escape_string` or anything that'd help you out.